# Update field with rownumber in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, rownum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: Updating a table column using ROWNUM in conjunction with ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094039/oracle-updating-a-table-column-using-rownum-in-conjunction-with-order-by-clause)

I have a query that returns an ordered set of records, and i want to copy the rownumber of each row in the result set into a particular field called Sequence on the record itself.

```
SELECT ROWNUM, ID
FROM (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE PARENT = 1
    ORDER BY SEQUENCE ASC
)
```

I have the ID of each row, and the `rownum` I want to put in the `SEQUENCE` field.  How can I loop through this result set and update the table accordingly?

Comment: It's very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094039/oracle-updating-a-table-column-using-rownum-in-conjunction-with-order-by-clause

Comment: @user1365247, Always try using Row_Number() instead of Rownum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
merge into mytable t
using (SELECT ROWNUM rn, ID
       FROM (
         SELECT ID 
         FROM MYTABLE 
         WHERE PARENT = 1
         ORDER BY SEQUENCE ASC
      )) S 
on (t.id=s.id)
when matched then update set
  t.sequence=s.rn
```

If id is not unique, you can, for sure:

```
merge into mytable t
using (SELECT ROWNUM rn, rwd
       FROM (
         SELECT rowid rwd
         FROM MYTABLE 
         WHERE PARENT = 1
         ORDER BY SEQUENCE ASC
      )) S 
on (t.rowid=s.rwd)
when matched then update set
  t.sequence=s.rn
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables`, please confirm.

Comment: if the id is not unique, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
  merge into EMP_MASTER x
  using (
          SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQUENCE) y
          FROM MYTABLE 
          WHERE PARENT = 1
         ) s on (s.ID=x.ID)
         when matched then update set
  x.sequence=s.y;
```

which works for unique IDs.

Comment: Are you sure this works?

Comment: Yes yes, it won't work.. i have edited with ROW_NUMBER() and MERGE.